# jQuery change hover on color, then return back to original color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, hover

I've got some buttons on a page whose color is changed via jQuery, illustrating which one's active. I'd like to add a color change ONLY when hovering, after which it's returned to the original color (which is dictated by jQuery) when left.

I first used css: `.showlink li:hover {color:#aaa;}` which works appropriately except for that when the pages are switched and jQuery changes the colors, it superceeds the CSS.

Then I decided to use simple jQuery that says when something's hovered on, change it's color. this doesn't completely work because it permanently changes the color. To mitigate this, I added in a bit to the function that returns it to a different color.

**is there some way I can return it to the original color from before it was changed on hover?**

```
// Changes color on hover
    $(function() {
        $('.showlink').hover(function(){
            $(this).css('color', '#aaa');
        },
        function(){
           $(this).css('color', '#f3f3f3');
        });
    });
//Changes color depending on which page is active, fades that page in
    $(function(){
        $('#show_one').css('color', '#ffcb06');
        $('#two, #three').hide();
    });

    $('.showlink').click(function(){
        $('.showlink').css('color', '#f3f3f3');
        $(this).css('color', '#ffcb06');
        var toShow = this.id.substr(5);
        $('div.page:visible').fadeOut(600, function(){
            $('#' + toShow).fadeIn(600);
        });
    });
```

Comment: if it doesn't matter, just kill the style attribute: $(this).removeAttr('style');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.showlink li:hover {color:#aaa !important;}
```

will superceede everything else.

Comment: Helped me, thank you. Sometimes the simple things are the best

Comment: Not sure I'm grokking how this can be the accepted answer when it doesn't seem to answer OPs original question. @DavidThomas' on the other hand clearly does. Weird. (I guess this is what OP actually wanted to know.) : /

Comment: As far as I remember and understand, he first tried to set the hover color with the css hover class without the `!important`, and that didn't work as soon as he changed the base color with jquery (because a style-tag-definition is higher rated than a cssclass-definition. A `!important` will rate this definition higher than everything else.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using an array to record the original color value, and use that in the `mouseleave` (second) function of `hover()`:

```
var originalColors = [];

// Changes color on hover
    $(function() {
        $('.showlink').hover(function(){
            originalColors[$(this).index('.showlink')] = $(this).css('color');
            $(this).css('color', '#aaa');
        },
        function(){
           $(this).css('color', originalColors[$(this).index('.showlink')]);
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sEfnp/1/).

You could also use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`:

```
// Changes color on hover
$(function() {
    $('.showlink').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sEfnp/2/).

Which would simply use CSS to apply the changed colour, and wouldn't require any kind of local storage of the CSS colour to reimplement it on `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it may be best to use CSS for this, there are times when JavaScript is preferred for one reason or another.  Even if CSS is always batter, the concept below should help you with other things in the future as well. So, that being said:

On hover, before changing color, get the current color and store it in the element's data. On hover-out, read that color back.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/TpmXd/

**Code:**

```
/* Changes color on hover */
$( function()
{
    $( '.showlink' ).hover(
        function()
        {
            /* Store jQuerized element for multiple use */
            var $this = $( this );

            $this
                /* Set the pre-color data */
                .data( 'prehovercolor', $this.css( 'color' ) )
                /* Set the new color */
                .css( 'color', '#aaa' );
        },
        function()
        {
            /* Store jQuerized element for multiple use */
            var $this = $( this );

            $this
                /* Set the color back to what is found in the pre-color data */
                .css( 'color', $this.data( 'prehovercolor') );
        }
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

when I have issues like this where original data on an element is lost, I call `myElement.setAttribute("oldcolor",myElement.style.color)` before changing it, and when I want to revert, I just set it to that.  `myElement.style.color = myElement.getAttribute("oldcolor")`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [.mouseout()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) this is like the inverse of .hover(). If the mouse goes over .showlink element and then off of it again, .mouseout() is called.

```
    $('.showlink').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color', '#aaa');
    }
    $('.showlink').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('color', '#bbb');
    }
```

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this. If you use JQUERY as a way to avoid .CSS and .HTML , this is the correct solution.